# Код ревью неофициального приложение для тостера?

Tags: android, инспекция-кода

Исправил все баги и недочеты что написали в [прошлый раз](https://toster.ru/q/461975), добавил нормальное отображение текста и фотографии, теперь ссылка будет ссылкой, фотка фоткой и тд...

Добавил проект этот в [github](https://github.com/artem54325/AndroidToster)

И переписал его, чтобы он удовлетворял принципам MVP (Хотя не уверен т.к. model имеет ссылку на Presenter)

Прошу подсказать с ревью кода

Comment: А в Kotlin определение, например, класса `CommentAnswerObject` будет занимать всего одну строку со всем тем же функционалом... :)

Comment: @rjhdby - Я посмотрю, а как вам весь код?? И как сделать, чтобы больше походил на MVP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По одному классу CommentAnswerObject. Думаю в остальных так же.

Зачем тут два огромных конструктора, фактически дублирующих друг друга?

```
public CommentAnswerObject(String urlImage, String name, String dogName, String text, String date, int numberUserComments, int numberLikeComents, boolean like, List<CommentToggleObject> toggleObjects) {
    this.urlImage = urlImage;
    this.name = name;
    this.dogName = dogName;
    this.text = text;
    this.date = date;
    this.numberUserComments = numberUserComments;
    this.numberLikeComents = numberLikeComents;
    this.like = like;
    this.toggleObjects = toggleObjects;
}

public CommentAnswerObject(String urlImage, String name, String dogName, String text, String date, int numberUserComments, int numberLikeComents, boolean like) {
    this.urlImage = urlImage;
    this.name = name;
    this.dogName = dogName;
    this.text = text;
    this.date = date;
    this.numberUserComments = numberUserComments;
    this.numberLikeComents = numberLikeComents;
    this.like = like;
}
```

Второй легко заменяется на

```
public CommentAnswerObject(String urlImage, String name, String dogName, String text, String date, int numberUserComments, int numberLikeComents, boolean like){
    this(urlImage, name, dogName, text, date, numberUserComments, numberLikeComments, like, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Такое огромное количество аргументов конструктора в 99% случаев говорит о том, что класс неправильно спроектирован.

Действительно ли в этом объекте нужны все эти поля? Как он используется? Какова его ЕДИНСТВЕННАЯ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬ?

Вот это экстрактится в класс `CommentContent`

```
this.urlImage = urlImage;
this.name = name;
this.dogName = dogName;    //имя собаки?
this.text = text;
```

Для чего используются эти два свойства?

```
this.numberUserComments = numberUserComments;
this.numberLikeComents = numberLikeComents;
```

По `CardObject`. Все то-же, но и еще: у вас мешанина методов. Один конструктор сверху, другие разбросаны по тексту. Почитайте Роберта Мартина "Чистый код" раздел "Вертикальное форматирование"

Класс `HTTP`. По феншую лучше `Http`. Статика - зло. В данном случае лучше применить паттерн `Singletone`. Он тоже не сахар, но при умелой готовке вполне себе ничего.

`ParsingPage` - вообще жесть. Чистый Код в руки и читать до дыр. Методы адски перегружены логикой и вызывают кровотечение из глаз при попытке понять, что происходит. Для начала разбить монстров на кучу мелких методов, выполняющих атомарные операции и понять, что половина из них дублирует друг друга. Вообще данный класс штуки на 4 разбивать надо, на глаз если.

Например класс `ParsingPage` метод `parsFullTag` (закроем глаза на статику), первая итерация "причесывания"

```
    private static NameAndTagFullInfoObject full;
    private static String html;

    public static NameAndTagFullInfoObject parsFullTag(String html) {
        full = new NameAndTagFullInfoObject();
        ParsingPage.html = html;

        setName();
        setUrlPhoto();
        if (html.contains("<div class=\"page-header__subtitle\" itemprop=\"jobTitle\">"))
            setDopName();
        if (html.contains("<div class=\"mini-counter__count mini-counter__count-contribution\">")) {
            setContribution();
        }
        setQuestion();
        setAnswer();
        setDecisions();
        setTextInto();

        return full;
    }

    private static void setName() {
        full.setName(html.split("<title>Информация по тегу «")[1].split("».")[0]);
    }

    private static void setUrlPhoto() {
        full.setUrlPhoto(tagContent("<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"", "\">",1 ));
    }

    private static void setDopName() {
        full.setDopName(divContent("page-header__subtitle\" itemprop=\"jobTitle",1 ));
    }

    private static void setContribution() {
        full.setContribution(joinNewLine(divContent("mini-counter__count mini-counter__count-contribution", 1), divContent("mini-counter__value", 1));
    }

    private static void setQuestion() {
        full.setQuestion(joinNewLine(divContent("mini-counter__count", 1), divContent("mini-counter__value", 2));
    }

    private static void setAnswer() {
        full.setAnswer(joinNewLine(divContent("mini-counter__count", 2), divContent("mini-counter__value", 3));
    }


    private static void setDecisions() {
        full.setDecisions(joinNewLine(divContent("mini-counter__count mini-counter__count-solutions", 1), divContent("mini-counter__value", 4)));
    }

    private static void setTextInto() {
        full.setTextInfo(trim(html.split("<div class=\"page__body\">")[1].split("<section class=\"section section_profile\">")[0]) + "\n");
    }


    private static String joinNewLine(String first, String second) {
        return first + "\n" + second;
    }

    private static String divContent(String div, int position) {
        return tagContent("<div class=\""+div+"\">", "</div>", position)
    }

    private static String tagContent(String start, String end, int position){
        return trim(html.split(start)[position].split(end)[0]);
    }

    private static String trim(String string) {
        return string.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("  ", "");
    }
```

1. Код метода стал читаемым. Просто читая его сверху вниз понятно, что он делает.
2. Можно легко найти и поменять/отладить отдельные операции. Например если изменилась разметка для поиска `setUrlPhoto` мы правим один простой метод, который находится мнгновенно.
3. Методы `trim`, `divContent`, `tagContent`, `joinNewLines` прекрасно применяются ко всем остальным методам вашего класса, катастрофически повышая их читаемость и сокращая размер.

Comment: думаю пока хватит

Comment: спасибо. Насчет конструктора, я согласен с вами, таким большим конструктором я так и не воспользовался. numberUserComments-нужен для показа кол-во комментариев у коммента пользователя, а второй соответственно лайков. Хорошо класс Http исправлю и изменю. А насчет ParsingPage - Может перекинуть часть методов в классы ...Object, чтобы туда отправлять html разметку, а в ответ отправлялся объект или сделать конструктор такой??

Comment: Я вам все же настоятельно советую прочитать "Чистый Код", хотя бы первые главы - там не очень много, за день можно осилить. Большинство вопросов отпадет сама собой. Если все же лень, то просто вооружитесь "принципом единственной ответственности" и критически посмотрите на свои классы и методы. Если совсем по простому, то один метод должен выполнять одну задачу. То же и с класами, но на более высоком уровне абстракции. Чуть попозже постараюсь пример в ответ добавить.

Comment: Спасибо, за книжку чуть позже я начну её читать. Не могу вас всё ещё понять с классом ParsingPage, ведь он выполняет только одну задачу, а каждый метод выполняет свою задачу. Думаю, поможет мне понять прочтение книги. А на что ещё стоит обратить внимание??

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Образно говоря, человек крутит руль, руль воздействует на рулевую планку, рулевая планка поворачивает колеса. При этом ответственность человека именно в повороте руля. Он не должен даже знать, каким образом руль воздействует на планку, гидроусилитель там, просто штырь или вообще электромоторы. Также и для руля - его задача воздействовать на планку и не заморачиваться тем, как именно она производит поворот колес.

Comment: Я читал такой пример уже много раз, но в данном случаи я не посчитал, что стоит на столько маленькие делать методы, а как понять когда какой размер метода нужен??

Comment: И вопрос вспомнил, забыл совсем о нем. В какую сторону смотреть, чтобы при повороте экрана, он только отрисовываелся, а не обновлялся активити или фрагмент полностью??

Comment: я вам больше скажу. После рефакториега этот метод всё ещё имеет 6 ответственностей на разных уровнях абстракции. 1) создаёт объект 2) наполняет его данными (это высокий уровень) 3,4) Проверяет необходимость contribution иdopName (средний) 5,6) Парсит строки для этих проверок (низкий)

Comment: штатно никак. при повороте экрана активити пересоздается. Такова логика работы.

Comment: Тогда разобью на 3 класса (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) как у вас написано.